# How to delete all the children of a Qt window?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a main window where I create the objects dynamically, so before making any new screen I have to first delete all the objects from the last screen. I was using this, and it was working great:

```
qDeleteAll(this->window->findChildren<QWidget*>());
```

But now I have this screen that has some `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`, and I made their parent the main window as well, and now I got a crash when I try to delete all the main window's children.

So my question is basically, how can I avoid this crash? How can I easily and safely delete all my main window's children including `GraphicsScene` and `GraphicsView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that your crash is being caused by a double delete.

QObject's parent/child relationships make it so that if the parent is deleted, its children are deleted as well.  So if you want to delete a widget and all of its descendants then all you need to do is delete the parent.

In your case I probably would make sure all of the dynamically created widgets belong to some kind of container widget/frame and delete that followed by recreating it.

Comment: do you mean 'descendants'?  Not sure if Qt widgets even need to be deleted, though.  They are reference counted, so if you reuse one or more, there is little cost in keeping them around.

Comment: QObjects will delete their children when deleted, but there's no reference counting built into the QObject system.  It's still up to the programmer to ensure that memory is managed properly, this just makes it a lot easier.

Comment: This worked great, I just created a QWidget that I use as a parent to all the objects, and made the main window the parent of this new QWidget, then I just delete it to delete all the objects.
Can you guys talk more about this memory issue? Should I do something to guarantee I will not run out of memory? My program is running in an embedded systems, so memory management is quite important! Thx.

Comment: From the QObject/QWidget side of things you should be fine. If you want to be extra paranoid you can always hook up to the QObject::destroyed() signal and verify that your widgets are getting deleted.

Comment: @chris - some QObjects are reference counted, or implicitly shared as the Trolls called it.  See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/implicit-sharing.html

Comment: Qt's implicit sharing has nothing to do with object deletion/cleanup. They use reference counting in the context you're referring to to manage shared pieces of memory and avoid unnecessary memory allocation, it has nothing to do with the kind of reference counting employed by smart pointers.